# How to modift the input list in TKINTER AUTOCOMPLETE to make it responsive

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, autocomplete

I have a GUI where a few fields must be completed, one of them usually has values that are repeated. These values are stored in an excel.

I would like to create an initial list out of the values of a given column and then to keep updating that column from new inputs that are stored in the same excel - they would be captured by 'surnames_list_df'.

```
... here it loads the DF and several other things.
surnames_list_df = list(set(df['Surname'].values))

MAIN = GUI()
MAIN.surnames_list.append(surnames_list_df) **
...
MAIN.mainloop()
```

Then in the GUI code:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            ...
            self.surnames_list = []
            ...
            # SURNAMES.
            tk.Label(self, text='Surname:').grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='e')
            self.surname_in = AutocompleteEntry(self, completevalues=self.surnames_list)
            self.surname_in.grid(column=1, row=11)
```

I believe the problem is where I put the **. I have tried several ways to update that list inside the Class but I haven't been sucessful. Might I need to send the list as an input in the class? I haven't touched that because I am not sure how I made it work and don't want to break it now that I have made it work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out and was modifying the Class to accept attributes.

```
... here it loads the DF and several other things.
surnames_list_df = list(set(df['Surname'].values))

MAIN = GUI(surnames_list_df)
...
MAIN.mainloop()
```

Then in the GUI code:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, surname_list_df, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        ...
        self.surnames_list = surname_list_df
        ...
        # SURNAMES.
        tk.Label(self, text='Surname:').grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='e')
        self.surname_in = AutocompleteEntry(self, completevalues=self.surnames_list)
        self.surname_in.grid(column=1, row=11)
```